# How do I align those divs perfectly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mysql, ejs

I am making a website with some facts and I made a "card" for each fact. It includes an image, a title and the fact itself.

When I display it, I get this. It automatically displays from mysql server. I expect it to be aligned and perfect.

Example of unaligned cards

[image: 1]
This is the index.js code (using express, mysql and ejs), index.ejs and css code:

INDEX.JS

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM facts WHERE 1', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(results.length) 
        var html = '';  
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {  
            html+=`
            <div class="special">
            <img src="http://localhost:3000/thumbnails/${results[i].image}">
            <h2>${results[i].title}</h2>
            <p>${results[i].fact}</p>
            </div>
            `;
        }
        

        res.render(__dirname + '/views/index.ejs', {results: html})
    })

})
```

INDEX.EJS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <%- include('components/head.ejs') %>
</head>
<body>
    <%- include('components/menu.ejs') %>
    <div style="margin-left:15%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">
        <h1>Welcome everyone</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <%- results %>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Longreach';
    src: url('Longreach.otf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gemstone';
    src: url('Gemstone.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('Roboto.ttf');
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Gemstone';
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: white;
    font-size: 60px;
}

p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

* {
    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);
    margin: 0;

}

.container .special {
    display: inline-block !important;
}

.special {
    display: inline-block !important;
    height: 500px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.special img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}


  
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
  
li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
  
li a.active {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    color: white;
}
  
li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

menu.ejs (component)

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin">Editor login</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: try using 

`display:flex;
align-items:stretch
`

in container class.

Comment: Hello everyone. I fixed it using overflow: hidden; and id. Thank you.